# how to connect Wall Mounting Monitor and computer

Tags: windows-7, windows

We want to connect different wall mounting monitor to one computer (server). Each monitor displays different contents. What is the best way to do this.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Where did you got stuck?

Comment: We have not started yet. We have a web application and we want people at production floor see their corresponding web page on their monitor. We would like to have a way by which all monitors are connected to one computer and each monitor is served respective content

Comment: Well, that's how it usually works. Buy monitors, buy computer, buy cables, connect computer with monitors using cables, done.

Comment: Touch screen is what we are looking for. Login, the screen displays QR code and the user has smart watch. Just read qr and login.

Comment: Each monitor will have different webpages. You mean this is easily acheivable

Answer (score 1):

If costs are not an issue - I would use two RasperryPi boards (or similar) and setup a streaming server on your server computer. I would have two different streams available from the server for each monitor. RaspberryPi should have WiFi adapter and access to that server computer. Softwarewise - VLC should do as a client. HDMI from RasperryPi should provide a video signal to the monitors.

Apparently, VLC should also do as a streaming server: [VideoLAN streaming solution](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html)

Comment: We want to display webpages on the monitor. Different users will have different pages. Login facility as well

Comment: Please describe the setup with more details. Do you users have separate keyboards, for example? How do they login? What are the limitations? Please describe the use case. You might get more useful suggestions this way.

Comment: Touch screen is what we are looking for (or else separate keyboard and mouse). Login, the screen displays QR code and the user has smart watch. Just read qr and login.